# syntx error, insert } to complet ClassBody

Tags: java

```
package me.san33der.pvp;

import java.util.Random;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.enchantments.Enchantment;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.inventory.meta.ItemMeta;
import org.bukkit.plugin.PluginManager;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

import me.san33der.pvp.listeners;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {

private static Main instance;

public void log(String string) {

}

public static Main getInstance() {
    return instance;

}

public void registerListeners() {
    PluginManager pm = getServer().getPluginManager();
    pm.registerEvents(new listeners(this), this);

}

public void registerCommands() {
    // not used yet

}

@Override
public void onEnable() {
    getLogger().info("has been enabled");
    instance = this;

    registerListeners();
    registerCommands();

}

@Override
public void onDisable() {
    getLogger().info("has been disabled");
    instance = null;
}

// commands

@Override
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commendlabel, String[] args) {



    // starter command
    if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("starter") && sender instanceof Player) {

        Player p = (Player) sender;
        p.getInventory().clear();
        ItemStack starterbow = new ItemStack(Material.BOW);
        ItemMeta m = starterbow.getItemMeta();
        m.setDisplayName(ChatColor.GREEN + "starterbow");
        starterbow.setItemMeta(m);
        starterbow.addEnchantment(Enchantment.ARROW_FIRE, 1);
        starterbow.addEnchantment(Enchantment.ARROW_INFINITE, 1);
        p.getInventory().addItem(starterbow);
        p.getInventory().addItem(new ItemStack(Material.ARROW));
        p.getInventory().setChestplate(new ItemStack(Material.IRON_CHESTPLATE));
        p.getInventory().setLeggings(new ItemStack(Material.IRON_LEGGINGS));
        p.getInventory().setBoots(new ItemStack(Material.IRON_BOOTS));
        p.getInventory().setHelmet(new ItemStack(Material.IRON_HELMET));
        p.setMaxHealth(50);
        p.setHealth(50);
        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "YOU WAS GIVING THE" + ChatColor.YELLOW + " starterkit");
    }

        return false;




// end of starter command

// amateur command
if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("amateur")&&sender instanceof Player) {



     Player p = (Player) sender;


    p.getInventory().clear();
    ItemStack amateurbow = new ItemStack(Material.BOW);
    ItemMeta n = amateurbow.getItemMeta();
    n.setDisplayName(ChatColor.YELLOW + "amateurbow");
    amateurbow.setItemMeta(n);
    amateurbow.addEnchantment(Enchantment.ARROW_FIRE, 1);
    amateurbow.addEnchantment(Enchantment.ARROW_INFINITE, 1);
    ItemStack amateursword = new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_SWORD);
    ItemMeta m = amateursword.getItemMeta();
    m.setDisplayName(ChatColor.YELLOW + "amateursword");
    amateursword.setItemMeta(m);
    amateursword.addEnchantment(Enchantment.FIRE_ASPECT, 2);
    amateursword.addEnchantment(Enchantment.KNOCKBACK, 2);
    p.getInventory().setChestplate(new ItemStack(Material.IRON_CHESTPLATE));
    p.getInventory().setBoots(new ItemStack(Material.IRON_BOOTS));
    p.getInventory().setHelmet(new ItemStack(Material.IRON_HELMET));
    p.getInventory().setLeggings(new ItemStack(Material.IRON_LEGGINGS));
    p.getInventory().addItem(amateursword);
    p.getInventory().addItem(amateurbow);
    p.getInventory().addItem(new ItemStack(Material.ARROW, 1));
    p.setMaxHealth(30);
    p.setHealth(30);
    p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "you was given the" + ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + " amateurkit");

    return false;
}
// random teleport
if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("teleportme")&&sender instanceof Player) {



    Player player = (Player) sender;


    Location originalLocation = player.getLocation();

    Random random = new Random();

    Location teleportLocation = null;

    int x = random.nextInt(10) + 1;
    int y = 30;
    int z = random.nextInt(10) + 1;

    boolean isOnLand = false;

    while (isOnLand == false) {

        teleportLocation = new Location(player.getWorld(), x, y, z);

        if (teleportLocation.getBlock().getType() != Material.AIR) {
            isOnLand = true;
        } else
            y--;

    }

    player.teleport(new Location(player.getWorld(), teleportLocation.getX(), teleportLocation.getY() + 1,
            teleportLocation.getZ()));

    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You have been teleported "
            + (int) teleportLocation.distance(originalLocation) + " blocks away!");

    return true;



return false;

// spawn
if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("spawn")&&sender instanceof Player)

{
    Player p = (Player) sender;
    p.teleport(p.getWorld().getSpawnLocation());
    p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "you have been teleported to spawn");

    return false;


    // setspawn
    if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("setspawn") && sender instanceof Player) {

        p.getWorld().setSpawnLocation(p.getLocation().getBlockX(), p.getLocation().getBlockY(),
                p.getLocation().getBlockZ());
        p.sendMessage("spawn location has been set at world" + p.getWorld().getName());

    }

    return false;

}

}
}
```

what is wrong with it i dont get it what i did wrong.

I'd appreciate a thorough explanation since I just started working with java and i want to learn from my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your indentation and bracketing. Each method should have an opening and closing curly bracket. The error that you're getting is caused by a missing bracket somewhere, meaning that the compiler thinks that you've not closed the class properly.

Comment: An error that large suggests that the bracketing is still wrong - what does the error message say?

Comment: `unreachable code` means that there's something above that section that's causing this method to terminate, so you never reach the code below. I suspect it's the `return false;` statement. Double check your bracketing again - make sure that every method, loop, if etc... has an opening and closing curly bracket.